# How can i understand a web site's language which is written by url rewriting method?

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm wondering. Is there any way or online service for learning?

Comment: I truly don't understand the question. Please elaborate.

Comment: imagine that please there is a web site which is online and thats url like that http://www.site.com/about-url-rewriting when i look its html code output i can not understand that web site's server side language. (php, asp, aspx etc.) i wondered is there any way or online service to understand? i hope this explain was clear.

Comment: Kerberos, do a Google search for Url Rewriting or Url Rewriting Tutorial.  That should get you started.  If you want language-specifics, include the language (e.g. php) as part of your search terms.

Comment: i think, i could not explain clearly. i know, how to do url rewriting. i want to learn whichever web site's orginal server side language which that written by url rewriting method. english is not my orginal language. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the HTTP headers and make an educated guess. You could for instance try http://network-tools.com, there is a tool to get HTTP headers there.

(voted to move the question to superuser.com, BTW)

Comment: thank you. i tried your sugget on from http://network-tools.com but that did not give me any information about site's header.

Comment: Try this link: http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=httphead&host=www.tempuri.org, replace ´www.tempuri.org´ with whatever site you want to check.

Comment: okay sorry, that was my fault. i understood how to check. thanks again.

Comment: You may see what modules for web server are installed, but not which is used. And mod_cgi or mod_fcgid is most frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no certain way to determine server language used by just viewing the web page.

There may be some clues like urls ending in php or jsp or asp(x). But honestly, it can be a trick.

Why would you need such a thing?